# Understanding and Resolving Singularities in Stereo Rectification using Multiple View Geometry

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-vision, geometry

I am currently working on implementing a stereo rectification algorithm based on the method described in the book "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision (MVG)," specifically in Section 11.12 and Corollary 11.4. My question revolves around understanding the matrix $M$ and how to calculate it effectively.

In the MVG book, it is explained that the rectification process involves constructing $H_0 = H' * M$, where M is a 3x3 submatrix of the camera matrix. MVG provides guidance on how to create this $M$ in Result A4.4 as $M = [e']_x * F$, where the first term is the skew-symmetric matrix of the epipole in the second image, and $F$ is the fundamental matrix.

The issue I encounter during implementation is that the matrix $M$ turns out to be singular, making it impossible to invert in the subsequent rectification process. My goal is to find a proper solution to prevent this singularity while ensuring the final rectified image quality remains satisfactory.

Upon investigating the [implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/f3c724d449b6431c407611fcc5d1ecedfe81e77d/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp#L3002) of the `cvStereoRectifyUncalibrated` function in OpenCV, I noticed an additional 3x3 matrix `E2_111` being introduced:

```
double e2_111[] =
{
    e2[0], e2[0], e2[0],
    e2[1], e2[1], e2[1],
    e2[2], e2[2], e2[2],
};
```

Could you please explain the mathematical basis for the addition of the `E2_111` matrix in the OpenCV implementation? How does this matrix help in resolving the singularity issue, and why is it not explicitly mentioned in the MVG book? Also, how to know if `E2_111` is an optimal choice? (I actually tried some random matrix but didn't work as well as `E2_111`)

Are there alternative methods or modifications to the calculation of $M$ that can prevent it from becoming singular while maintaining the quality of the final rectified image?

Thank you.